# How Create Web-Page

Tags: html, css, web

I want to make a page on the site that was shown to the user only once,never found how to do it,I will be glad if you share your opinion on how to do it.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, a complete webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  My first webpage
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice and sleek, performant and responsive. You have my +1